# "String or binary data would be truncated" error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having an interesting problem, that just arose a couple weeks ago, with my SQL server.  I use Crystal Reports to execute regular queries of my DB, and one of my reports recently started failing sometimes, and succeeding other times. Let me start by saying that I am not a true DBA, I am just taking over this DB and Crystal Reports setup from someone else.  I did not write the query in question.

I have done some digging, and I seem to have found the syntax that is causing the problem.  It is a fairly long query, so I won't include it all, unless requested.  This query pulls data based on the day it is today. Some days, the query succeeds, and some days it fails.  When it fails, the error code is:

```
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

Here is the syntax that seems to be causing the problem:

```
DECLARE @LastWeekDay AS DATETIME

SET @LastWeekDay = 
(SELECT
CASE
   WHEN DATEPART ( weekday, GETDATE() ) = 2 THEN
      CAST ( DATEADD ( day, -3, GETDATE() ) AS DATE )
   WHEN DATEPART ( weekday, GETDATE() ) = 1 THEN
      CAST ( DATEADD ( day, -2, GETDATE() ) AS DATE )
   ELSE
      CAST ( DATEADD ( day, -1, GETDATE() ) AS DATE )
END)
```

If I start to manipulate this query, by entering static dates, rather than use the GETDATE() function.  I get mixed results.  Today, the report is working, so if I throw in today's date, like this, it works, and gives me the result I'm looking for:

```
DECLARE @LastWeekDay AS DATETIME

SET @LastWeekDay = 
(SELECT
CASE
   WHEN DATEPART ( weekday, '1/22/2015' ) = 2 THEN
      CAST ( DATEADD ( day, -3, '1/22/2015' ) AS DATE )
   WHEN DATEPART ( weekday, '1/22/2015' ) = 1 THEN
      CAST ( DATEADD ( day, -2, '1/22/2015' ) AS DATE )
   ELSE
      CAST ( DATEADD ( day, -1, '1/22/2015' ) AS DATE )
END)
```

However, if I change the date to 1/21/2015, it fails with this error code:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 310
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I went down to line 310, to see what the issue is.  And here is the code at 310.

```
308 DECLARE @Queue TABLE ( LoanID varchar(8), LoanType varchar(12), CreditApproval DATE )
309 
310 INSERT INTO @Queue ( LoanID, LoanType, CreditApproval )
311 SELECT
312 "_364" LoanID,
313 "_1172" LoanType,
314 "_2300" CreditApproval
```

I have tried increasing the character count on my field declarations, but that doesn't seem to work.  I just can't figure out why some dates produce results, and some days produce errors.

Here is a sample of the past couple weeks, and dates that work/produce an error:

```
1/22   Works
1/21   Error
1/20   Works
1/19   Works
1/16   Error
1/15   Error
1/14   Works
1/13   Works
1/12   Error
1/9    Works
1/8    Works
1/7    Error
```

All dates 1/6 and previous seems to work just fine. What could be causing this error?

Comment: `CreditApproval` is a date field and you are inserting  `_2300`

Comment: @NoDisplayName identified the problem but you could greatly simplify the sql you posted by removing all the casts to date and just declare your variable as a date instead of datetime.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to include all 370 lines, but _2300 is actually a declared field name, not a value.  Here is an example of that:  WHERE 

"_2300" = @LastWeekDay AND

Comment: Does anyone else have any ideas.  Today is another day where the query fails with the "String or binary data would be truncated" error message.  And just to clarify again, I'm not trying to pass the value "_2300" into the date field.  I'm telling it to look at the value of field "_2300", which is declared earlier in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem.  At some point the length of one of my fields had changed in SQL from VARCHAR(12) to VARCHAR(25).  Some days, the value queried was less than 12 characters, so there was no problem.  Other days, the value exceeded 12, and caused an error when you tried to insert it into the "Loan Type" field.  I just changed the length of my field in my declaration to 25 characters.  Now I have no more problems.  Here is my new declaration.

```
DECLARE @Queue TABLE ( LoanID varchar(8), LoanType varchar(25), CreditApproval DATE )

INSERT INTO @Queue ( LoanID, LoanType, CreditApproval )
SELECT
"_364" LoanID,
"_1172" LoanType,
"_2300" CreditApproval

FROM
(((emdbuser.LOANXDB_S_02 s2
INNER JOIN emdbuser.LOANXDB_S_06 s6 ON s2.XrefId = s6.XrefId )
INNER JOIN emdbuser.LOANXDB_S_01 s1 ON s2.XrefId = s1.XrefId )
INNER JOIN emdbuser.LOANXDB_S_03 s3 ON s2.XrefId = s3.XrefId )
INNER JOIN emdbuser.LOANXDB_D_02 d2 ON s2.XrefID = d2.XrefId
```

There was also one more declaration, further down in my query, where I had to change the field length to 25.  All is well now.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would edit your question so that it no longer gives the impression that the problem is date related. As it stands now, it is quite misleading.